# Не соответствие полей модели и таблицы в БД

Tags: golang

Пользуюсь go-pg, и не могу разобраться как мне решить проблему когда кол-во полей модели не совпадает с количеством полей в БД

```
type UnitModel struct {
    Id int
    Name string

    TableName struct{} `sql:"unit"`
}

var unit UnitModel
err := db.Model(&unit).Where("id = ?", id).Select()
```

pg: can't find column alter_name in model

Comment: Я смотрел исходники и пришел к выводу, что без исправления библиотеки с этим ничего сделать нельзя. Править не стал, т.к. моя задача краткосрочна и написания патча не оправдалось бы по времени.

Answer (score 1):

В версии 4.8.10 go-pg это поведение изменено. Теперь если в таблице есть поля, которых нету в структуре, ошибка падать не будет.